# Compress files menu: password grayed out

Tags: password, mate, compression

I am trying to password protect a compressed file, but the option to do so is greyed out. I am using Ubuntu 14.02 Mate.

How can i password protect a compressed file?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selected compression option does not support it. Select a different one from the list after the filename. According to the documentation:

```
Currently, only 7-Zip, ZIP, RAR and ARJ archives support encryption
```